# PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item

Tags: oracle, collections, oracle11g

I have declared a nested table type in a package, so don't understand the errors I am receiving here.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE model_collection_types
IS                                                    
  TYPE project_sk_list IS TABLE OF dw_dim_project.project_sk%TYPE;

END model_collection_types;
/

DECLARE      
  drug_projects model_collection_types.project_sk_list;

  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT a.project_sk
    FROM dw_dim_project a 
    INNER JOIN dw_dim_program b ON a.program_sk = b.program_sk
    WHERE a.status_cd = 1
          AND b.program_category_desc = 'DRUG'
          AND a.state = 'ACTIVE';

BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO drug_projects;
  CLOSE c1;

  dbms_output.put_line(drug_projects.count || ' projects insertred into drug_projects table');

  FOR l_row IN drug_projects.first .. drug_projects.last
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('Project_SK : ' || l_row || ' ' || drug_projects(l_row));
  END LOOP;

  SELECT column_value
    FROM TABLE (drug_projects) c;
END;
/
```

Any advice appreciated,  I have tried `SELECT * FROM COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(drug_projects)` also.

Comment: I assume that the full stack trace shows the error to be coming from the last line of code, your `SELECT` statement.  What are you trying to accomplish there?  An anonymous PL/SQL block can't just run a `SELECT` statement, it has to do something with the result.  But it doesn't make sense to do anything with the result because you already have the data in a collection.

Comment: Just trying to learn how to use collections, and wanted to see how to use them in select statements....yes, comment out the select statement and it runs OK.  I guess I could do a select into to see if it works at least.